# Updating nested array of documents as object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called 'A' with thousands of documents in it. Here grades is the array of sub documents which consist attribute questions which is array of number like below

```
{ "_id" : 1,
      "grades" : [
        { type: "quiz", questions: [ 10, 8, 5 ] },
        { type: "quiz", questions: [ 8, 9, 6 ] },
        { type: "hw", questions: [ 5, 4, 3 ] },
        { type: "exam", questions: [ 25, 10, 23, 0 ] }
      ]
   }
```

In order to add additional feature we have to modify the format of questions and make it array of documents which has two fields one is **number** (which will inherit the old data) and another one is **attempts**(by default it will be empty array and may have value 'P'- Pass or 'F'- Fail). After this transformation the document should look like below

```
{ "_id" : 1,
      "grades" : [
        { 
          type: "quiz",
          questions:[ 
                      { number: 10, attempts: ['F', 'P'] },
                      { number: 8, attempts: [] },
                      { number: 5, attempts: ['P'] }
                    ] 
        },
        { 
          type: "quiz", 
          questions: 
                    [ 
                     { number: 8, attempts: ['F', 'P'] },
                     { number: 9, attempts: [] },
                     { number: 6, attempts: ['P'] }
                    ] 
        },
        { 
          type: "hw",
          questions: 
                    [ 
                       { number: 5, attempts: ['F', 'P'] },
                       { number: 4, attempts: [] },
                       { number: 3, attempts: ['P'] }
                    ]
        },
        {
           type: "exam",
           questions: 
                     [ 
                       { number: 25, attempts: ['F', 'P'] },
                       { number: 10, attempts: [] },
                       { number: 23, attempts: ['P'] },
                       { number: 0, attempts: ['P', 'P'] }
                     ] 
        }
      ]
   }
```

Appreciate for all the help

Answer (score 1):

You can test yourself here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZEp_vk5hhf7

**Brief explanation:**
You have to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) two times.

- First you have to loop the `$grades` field, because he is an array.
- As you are looping through `$grades` array, you have to loop through the `$questions` field, because he is an array too.

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "grades": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$grades",
          "as": "g",
          "in": {
            "type": "$$g.type",
            "questions": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$g.questions",
                "as": "q",
                "in": {
                  "number": "$$q",
                  "attempts": []
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "grades": [
      {
        "questions": [
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 10
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 8
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 5
          }
        ],
        "type": "quiz"
      },
      {
        "questions": [
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 8
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 9
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 6
          }
        ],
        "type": "quiz"
      },
      {
        "questions": [
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 5
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 4
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 3
          }
        ],
        "type": "hw"
      },
      {
        "questions": [
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 25
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 10
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 23
          },
          {
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 0
          }
        ],
        "type": "exam"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: igorkf, this works fine but this is just projection. I would like to update the questions field like [{
            "attempts": [],
            "number": 8
          }]